# Erro no vinculo do ManytoManyField do usário

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

criei uma rotina aonde se cadastra um centro de custo. Esse centro de custo sao vinculados por meio de um ManyToManyField quando vou cadastrar o Usuário. Abaixo os models.py desses cadastro:

models do usuário:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    primeiro_nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    ultimo_nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    centrodecusto_usuario = models.ManyToManyField(CentroDeCusto, blank=True)
    perfil_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    permissao_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Permissao, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_usuario')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.primeiro_nome
```

E esse é o model do centro de custo:

```
class CentroDeCusto(models.Model):
    numero_centro = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    nome_centro = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    centro_de_custo = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    user_respon = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    vinculo_natureza = models.ManyToManyField(NaturezaOrcamentaria)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_centrodecusto')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.centro_de_custo
```

Depois disso criei um models aonde será cadastrado um orçamento. Esse orçamento é cadastrado informando o centro de custo, uma natureza orçamentária, a data e o valor. Conforme o Model abaixo:

```
class  CadastroOrcamento(models.Model):
    cc_cadastro_orcamento = models.ForeignKey(CentroDeCusto, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    no_cadastro_orcamento = models.ForeignKey(NaturezaOrcamentaria, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    valor_cadastro_orcamento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    data_cadastro_orcamento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    obs_cadastro_orcamento = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_cadastro_orcamento')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.obs_cadastro_orcamento
```

O que eu quero fazer: quando o usuário entrar para cadastrar o orçamento, aonde ele vai informar o centro de custo, so vai aparecer os centros de custo que ele foi vinculado no models de cadastro de usuário.

O que tentei fazer: Criei um forms.py dentro da minha app aonde faço o cadastro do orçamento. Nele coloquei a condição para aparecer somente o centro de custo que o usuário foi vinculado, conforme abaixo:

```
class CadastroOrcamentoForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CadastroOrcamentoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cc_cadastro_orcamento'].queryset = Usuario.objects.filter(centrodecusto_usuario=user.usuario.centrodecusto_usuario)

    class Meta:
        model = CadastroOrcamento
        fields = ['cc_cadastro_orcamento', 'no_cadastro_orcamento', 'no_cadastro_orcamento', 'valor_cadastro_orcamento', 'data_cadastro_orcamento', 'obs_cadastro_orcamento']
```

Nas minhas views aonde edito e crio o orçamento coloquei os seguintes codigos:

Editar orçamento:

```
class CadastroOrcamentoEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = CadastroOrcamento
    form_class = CadastroOrcamentoForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CadastroOrcamentoList, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

criar orçamento:

```
class CadastroOrcamentoCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = CadastroOrcamento
    form_class = CadastroOrcamentoForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CadastroOrcamentoCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

faço a makemigrations e o migrate e tudo vai bem. Quando entro para cadastrar o orçamento me da o seguinte track de erro:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 07, 2020 - 19:56:08
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'financial_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /cadastro-orcamento/novo/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1768, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/apps/cadastro_orcamento/forms.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.fields['cc_cadastro_orcamento'].queryset = Usuario.objects.filter(centrodecusto_usuario=user.usuario.centrodecusto_usuario)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/Users/felipegomes/financial_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10bb44fd0>.
[07/Feb/2020 19:56:17] "GET /cadastro-orcamento/novo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 151588
```

Já procurei de tudo na internet e nao achei nada que me ajudasse.

Se conseguirem me ajudar será bem valido.

Answer (score 0):

Acertei o filtro do forms e funcionou. Ficou dessa forma:

```
self.fields['cc_cadastro_orcamento'].queryset = user.usuario.centrodecusto_usuario.all()
```